# How to set up Testem to support Angular 2 unit tests?

Tags: angular, testem

I have been using Testem to write unit tests for Angular 1 apps for a while now, I like it.

I'm migrating my dev framework from Angular 1 to Angular 2. I'm trying to avoid investing too much time figuring out how to set up Testem in Angular 2. I would love to hear from some one who has done it!

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Regards 
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this by switching from Linaman to angular-cli